# C getopt,strdup function code

Tags: c

```
  while ((c = getopt(ac, av, "r:u:p:h:P:s:S:t:iRbo:n:")) != EOF)
        {
            switch(c)
                {
                case 'b':
                    isbsd++;
                    break;
                case 'R':
                    detectos++;
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    root = strdup(optarg);
                    break;
                case 'i':
                    is_scramble = 1;
                    break;
                case 's':
                    saddr = strtoul(optarg, 0, 0);
                    break;
                case 't':
                    timeout = strtoul(optarg, 0, 0);
                    break;
                case 'S':
                    size = strtoul(optarg, 0, 0);
                    break;
                case 'u':
                    user = strdup(optarg);
                    break;
                case 'p':
                    pass = strdup(optarg);
                    break;
                case 'h':
                    host = strdup(optarg);
                    break;
                case 'P':
                    port = strtoul(optarg, 0, 0);
                    break;
                case 'o':
                    heapbase = strtoul(optarg, 0, 0);
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    scnum = strtoul(optarg, 0, 0);
                    break;
                default:
                    usage(av[0]);
                }
        }
```

I am quite new to getopt function, and have never used it. (ac is argc, av is argv)

So, how does this code operate? What I am getting confused is how "r:u..." thing works.

Also, what does strdup and strtoul do in this code?

Thanks.

Comment: "what does strdup and strtoul do in this code?" Have you tried reading the documentation to find out what these functions do?

Comment: Did you read the [docs for getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html) ? It's all explained there.

Answer (score 2):

You should really [research your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) before posting it on StackOverflow.  That said, there's a [man page for getopt](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getopt) which describes the `optstring` argument:

> optstring is a string containing the legitimate option characters. If such a character is followed by a colon, the option requires an argument, so getopt() places a pointer to the following text in the same argv-element, or the text of the following argv-element, in optarg. Two colons mean an option takes an optional arg; if there is text in the current argv-element (i.e., in the same word as the option name itself, for example, "-oarg"), then it is returned in optarg, otherwise optarg is set to zero. This is a GNU extension. If optstring contains W followed by a semicolon, then -W foo is treated as the long option --foo. (The -W option is reserved by POSIX.2 for implementation extensions.) This behavior is a GNU extension, not available with libraries before glibc 2.

`strdup` is a standard C library function to copy a string to a newly allocated buffer (so you don't mess up someone else's copy), and `strtoul` converts a string into an unsigned long.

Answer (score 1):

The colon (`:`) means that the option (the single letter) must be followed by an argument. This argument will be stored in "optarg".

for more information, look here: http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html

[`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/strdup.html) is a POSIX convenience function that allocates a buffer and copies the source character array to the destination.

[`strtoul()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/strtoul/) is a function for parsing unsigned integers from a string and return them as unsigned long.

Answer (score 0):

1. the r:u:.... : The letters represent a flag that you can specify in the command line, the : indicates that an extra argument is required there
2. strdup makes a copy of a string
3. strtoul converts a string into an unsigned long